# Does okhttp authenticator handle 403 error?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using `Okhttp Authenticator` for updating my `JWT` tokens. But there is a problem, that the `authenticate()` method is called, when I'm getting 401 from backend. But when I'm getting 403 - token expired, the `authenticate()` method doesn't get called. Is there any good topic about how the `authenticator()` method works or can we call it manually? And also the main question - does it handle 403 response?

Comment: Why are you sending `403` from the server when it's an authentication problem you should be sending a `401` from the server.

Comment: I'm not doing the backend)) For me it's weird too)) So what do you think, does `Okhttp Authenticator` handles `403`? I want to find any source to find information about this, but  I can't find it) Thank you.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm not sure but you should be talking to your backend guys and don't complicate this.

Comment: Thanks OhhhThatVarun

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own interceptor to catch the 403, renew the token and retry.

It's essentially what this interceptor in my project does https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/5163436f8bcb2526e8be7b72d59d99a9db433848/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/okurl/authenticator/RenewingInterceptor.kt